# Как выполнить проверку что переменная приняла значение str или int и выполнилась в цикле на python?

Tags: python, функции

```
my_list1 = ["Vasya", 23, "China", 98, "Иван"]
a = len(my_list1)


def fun1():
    b = input("Выберите число из списка от 0 до {} или любые числа в этом диапазоне через пробел, "
              "либо введите число  больше чем {}:\n".format(a - 1, a - 1))
    if(type(b)==str):
        print("Вы ввели некорректное значение!")
        fun1()
    else:
        b = list(map(int, b.split()))
        for i in b:
            if i < a:
                print(my_list1[i])
            elif i >= a:
                print("Весь список: ", my_list1)


fun1()
while True:
    answer = str(input("Хотите повторить? (Да\Нет):\n"))
    if answer.lower() == "да":
        fun1()
    elif answer.lower() == "нет":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Некорректный ввод, повторите!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-бы проверить является ли объект экземпляром указанного класса (в вашем случай: **str** или **int**) можно использовать функцию **isinstance()**

```
if isinstance(b, str):
    print("Вы ввели некорректное значение!")
    fun1()
```

Метод **b.isalpha()** проверяет состоит ли строка только только из символов. Например строка 'China1' - не пройдет проверку

Comment: не из "символов", а из букв алфавита. ``1`` - тоже символ.

Comment: верно, спасибо, что поправили

Answer (score 0):

Это помогло, кому может пригодится.

```
if b.isalpha():
    print("Вы ввели некорректное значение!")
    fun1()
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).